# Sum of the numbers between 1 to 100

Tags: assembly, x86, windbg, masm, masm32

I'm a newbish in ASM.
I'm trying to accomplish a simple task - sum of the numbers between 1 to 100, `eax` will hold the sum.
e.g: `1 + 2 + 3 + .. + 100`

So here's the relevant code:

```
    XOR eax, eax ;; Set eax to 0
MOV ecx, 100 ;; We will loop 100 times
my_loop:
    ADD eax, ecx ;; We add the ecx register value to eax, ecx decreses by 1 every iteration untill he reaches 0
LOOP my_loop
  ;;Exit the program, eax is the exit code
push eax
call ExitProcess
```

When I debug the exe file, `eax` is being 0. How is it possible?

BTW, is there any easy way to print the value of `EAX` to the console, instead of opening Windbg to check its value?

Comment: You're not showing much of your code, but since you're calling `ExitProcess` I assume you're linking with the Windows API. So, you should have access to `MessageBox` as a means of popping up a window with some information. You can also use `invoke`.

Comment: @mbratch I'm linking it with masm32 and kernel32, anyway, the program should work and eax should really have the sum of 1 + 2 + 3 +.. + 100?

Comment: You had asked in your post about how to display values without the debugger, so that was my suggestion. You could also look up `int 21h` if you're using the console. I'm not sure why `eax` would be `0` unless the debugger isn't showing it to you at that location (right before or after the `push`).

Comment: In the MASM32 folder, there should be a folder called "vkdebug".  In this folder look at the examples.  This has a few macros that print out various things to a window for debugging.

Comment: Seems to me `mov eax, 5050` would be easiest. Or if you have to do a computation just take 100(100+1)/2 = 5050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program, a little bit adapted for [FreshLib](http://fresh.flatassembler.net) works like a charm. The core of the program is the same, I simply added some console output. (and well, it is FASM syntax) So, you simply missed to notice that the program is working properly.

```
include "%lib%/freshlib.inc"

@BinaryType console

include "%lib%/freshlib.asm"

start:
        InitializeAll

        XOR  eax, eax ;; Set eax to 0
        MOV  ecx, 100 ;; We will loop 100 times
my_loop:
        ADD  eax, ecx ;; We add the ecx register value to eax, ecx decreses by 1 every iteration untill he reaches 0
        LOOP my_loop
  ;;Exit the program, eax is the exit code
        mov  ebx, eax

        stdcall NumToStr, ebx, ntsDec or ntsSigned
        stdcall FileWriteString, [STDOUT], eax

        stdcall FileReadLine, [STDIN]  ; in order to pause until ENTER is pressed.

        stdcall TerminateAll, ebx 

@AllDataEmbeded
@AllImportEmbeded
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any easy way to keep the console opened so that I can actually see the result? XD

Comment: @idish - well, I added it to the answer. And as long as the "ExitProcess" was the sole Win32 function, I replaced it with "TerminateAll". This way the program can be compiled for Windows and Linux - simply set %TargetOS% to Win32 or Linux respectively.

Comment: I'm sorry for going a little off topic here.. but, I'm currently using the MASM32 Editor. I know that emu8086 lets you see the registers value, memory, etc. How can I achieve that task too in my editor?

Comment: I'm trying to use windbg for that purpose but struggling with the debugging.. I think I should just learn how to properly use Windbg..

Comment: Cool, I use OllyDbg now and it seems to be working :) It can only load exe files and not asm source files? I think that the disassembler of ollydbg gives a different code of my original source asm, is it even possible?

Comment: @idish - it is probably not so different. Maybe the syntax differs a little, but think creatively. :) Also, there are preferences for the disassembler, where the output can be adjusted a little.

Answer (score 0):

This works, though I am using Irvine32.inc library to print my result, just use your own method to print. The result is still in EAX

```
TITLE   SOF_Sum

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc ;may remove this and use your own thing

.code

MAIN PROC
    MOV EAX, 0 ; or XOR EAX, EAX - sets eax to 0
    MOV ECX, 100 ; loop counter - our loop will run 100 times

    myloop:
        ADD EAX, ECX ; adds ECX to EAX
    loop myloop

    call writedec ;displays decimal version of EAX, from Irvine32.inc, replace

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I think the important part here is the loop procedure, the others can be of your own design.

Hopefully this helps (:

JLL

Answer (score -2):

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
org 2000h
series dw 1234h,2345h,0abcdh,103fh,5555h
sum dw 00h
carry dw 00h
data ends
code segment
start:mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov ax,00h
mov bx,00h
mov cx,05h
mov si,2000h
go:add ax,[si]
adc bx,00h
inc si
inc si
dec cx
jnz go
mov sum,ax
mov carry,bx
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's just an incorrectly formatted dump of uncommented code, without any explanation.